# How can I get the "educated" badge when the documentation tour has been shut down?

Tags: bug, badges

I just stumbled over that... Is there a way to get it somehow or is the badge deprecated? If so, why can I still track it?

Comment: You can't get documentation badges anymore - so might want to make this clear there's a potential bug in being able to track something that's unattainable - I originally read this as asking "How do I get the badge?"...